# selecting first item in autocompletebox silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight autocompletebox which is filled with items. Does anyone know how to highlight the first item in the list so that, if the user presses enter, the item is chosen and the user doesn't necessarily have to use the mouse?

In other windows controls, you can use selectedindex = 0;

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested, you need to grab a reference to the child ListBox control of the AutoCompleteBox and use SelectedIndex on that.

Answer (score 2):

In the XAML set

IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is SelectedItem.  If you are doing it in code, you would just need something like autoCompleteControl.SelectedItem = listUsedToPopulate[0];

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Only one item is appearing in the list when the user types

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the good answers already given.

First, jesse's answer -- set `IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"`, simple -- populates the text box, after each keystroke, with the first item in the list.  When you press enter, then, the popup closes.  The reason I ended up not using this approach, is that it updates the `SelectedItem` immediately, without waiting for the user to press enter.

Sico's answer is what I used.  It requires subclassing the `AutoCompleteBox` control in order to access the `GetTemplateChild` method.  Here's the code:

```
public class ExtendedAutoCompleteBox : AutoCompleteBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            UpdateSelection();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSelection()
    {
        // get the source of the ListBox control inside the template
        var enumerator = ((Selector)GetTemplateChild("Selector")).ItemsSource.GetEnumerator();

        // update Selecteditem with the first item in the list
        enumerator.Reset();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var item = enumerator.Current;
            SelectedItem = item;

            // close the popup, highlight the text
            IsDropDownOpen = false;
            (TextBox)GetTemplateChild("Text").SelectAll();
        }
    }
}
```